# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:98

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##
 #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    access_log /tmp/bokeh.access.log;
    error_log /tmp/bokeh.error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

and tested with

```
sudo nginx -t
```

get

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:98
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy wit nginx, how can I fix the error ?

Comment: you should probably place `server` inside `http`.

Comment: @Louy thx. you are right :)

Answer (score 13):

As Louy pointed out, the answer in this is that the `server` directive needs to be nested in the `http` block, not at the same level.

Nginx helpfully has a [list of all the directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).

Note, for each directive (like the [server directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server)), the first block of documentation always includes a "Context" key, which details exactly which contexts the directive is allowed in.

This is a great resource to check for any "directive not allowed" error with Nginx. In the the case of the `server` directory, the only possible context is `http`, leaving only one possible fix.

Comment: is mail  also a possible choice for the context ?

Comment: @Hellolad Are you asking if `mail` is a valid context at all, or if `mail` is a valid context for a `server` directive?

Answer (score 2):

nginx.conf file structure should be like below

```
...
events {
    ...
}
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
    }
}
```